# Неправильный четырехугольник в фоне

Tags: android, xml, vector

Необходимо реализовать экран как на картинке.
Светлая область - ImageView с растянутой картинкой.
Черная область Layout с черным фоном (неправильный четырехугольник).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал Черную область сделать таким образом:

background

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="1000dp"
android:height="1000dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100">
<group android:name="triableGroup">
    <path
        android:name="triangle"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M 0 1000 L 1000 1000 L 1000 1000 L 1000 200 L 0 0 Z" />
</group>
```

Но

Но при разных экранах, неправильный четырехугольник отображается по разному. Как можно сделать так чтобы черная область растягивалась не теряя своего вида?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть проще разбить экран горизонтальной линией, а дизайнера попросить создать картинку с черным треугольником:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, это значительно упростить жизнь, как в написании кода, так и в его поддержке.

Comment: В Верхний ImageView вставляется картинка с соотношением типа 16:9 (имею ввиду что картинка широкая). Ширина match_parent а высота 300dp задается для ImageView, scaleType = centerCrope - это все для того чтобы на разных экранах верхняя картинка  выгладила более менее нормально и не нужно было под разные экраны вырезать картинки. Теперь, по вашему совету, я добавил еще один imageView на верхним и туда положил треугольник(картинка вроде 512х200) а ImageView - matchparent, height = 75dp, вроде выглядит нормально(не знаю как это будет смотреться на разных устройствах). Правильно я понял вашу идею?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!